# glob function not working with get_stylesheet_directory() function in Wordpress https child theme activated website

Tags: wordpress, glob

I am trying to get all the image files from a folder.I am using a wordpress website

This is the code I tried

```
$base_dir = trailingslashit(get_stylesheet_directory());
$dir      = 'images/';
$images   = glob($base_dir.$dir.'*.{png,gif,jpg}',GLOB_BRACE);
foreach($images as $image)
{
 echo ' <img src="'. str_replace(get_home_path(), get_home_url(), $image) .'" alt="...">';
}
```

The code is working correctly in my localhost website.But when I use the same code in my website the code is not working.The Image array is empty for me.
Note:Child theme is activated in my website and the website is HTPPS.

Any help.

Comment: Does `var_dump( $base_dir.$dir );` yield the correct directory on your website?

Comment: @Xhynk I am getting this as the result-------   string(0) ""

Comment: You want to access the image folder of main theme from child theme?

Comment: @Ravi the image folder is in main theme.

Comment: I will change the location from child theme to main theme,if option like that is possible

Comment: `get_stylesheet_directory()` gets the child themes location if activated - you need `get_templete_directory()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$base_dir = trailingslashit(get_template_directory());
$dir      = 'images/';
$images   = glob($base_dir.$dir.'*.{png,gif,jpg}');

foreach($images as $image) {
    $url = get_theme_file_uri($dir.basename($image));
    printf('<div class="dynamic item"><img src="%s" alt=""></div>', esc_url($url));
}
```

Comment: Not working. I am getting Array()  when tried this:

$images   = glob($base_dir.$dir.'*.{png,gif,jpg}',GLOB_BRACE);
print_r($images);

Comment: echo '<img src="'. str_replace($base_dir, trailingslashit(get_stylesheet_directory_uri()), $image) .'" alt="...">';

Answer (score 0):

This is due to `get_home_path()` function . Have you check whether the `get_home_path()` function return the data?

Please try to update below code. i.e. instead of `get_home_path()` use `$base_dir`. Check below snipet.

```
$base_dir = trailingslashit(get_stylesheet_directory());
$dir     = 'images/';
$images   = glob($base_dir.$dir.'*.{png,gif,jpg}',GLOB_BRACE);
foreach($images as $image){
echo '<img src="'. str_replace($base_dir, trailingslashit(get_stylesheet_directory_uri()), $image) .'" alt="...">';
}
```

Hope it will resolve your issue.
Thanks

Comment: Not working. I am getting Array() when tried this: $images = glob($base_dir.$dir.'*.{png,gif,jpg}',GLOB_BRACE); print_r($images);

Comment: The code is not entering to for loop.So this won't work

Comment: can you please provide the file or the updated code and link to the site?